# PLplot linker error

Tags: c, linker, cmake, shared-libraries

I am trying to use `PLplot` for visualization in a C project.

However, although the headers and the libraries seem to be correctly included (`cmake` returns no error), when I try to actually use some PLplot functions, I get errors similar to `undefined reference to 'c_plinit'` and `ld returned 1 exit status`

I guess it is a linker problem and it seems like a common problem. However, the stuff I found on google are either not applicable for my case or not detailed enough for a beginner like me.

Note that if I add in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
message(${PLplot_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(${PLplot_LIBRARY_DIRS})
message(${PLplot_LIBRARIES})
```

I get the following output:

```
/usr/local/include/plplot
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/libplplotcxxd.so
```

Please help!

**EDIT**:
The relevant lines from CMakeLists.txt are as follows:

```
# The directory with the FindPLplot module
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

FIND_PACKAGE(PLplot REQUIRED)
SET(PLplot_LIBRARIES ${PLplot_LIBRARIES} ${PLplot_cxx_LIBRARY})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PLplot_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${PLplot_LIBRARY_DIRS})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(main main.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main ${PLplot_LIBRARIES})
INSTALL(TARGETS main DESTINATION bin)
```

And then, under a folder called `cmake`, there is a `FindPLplot.cmake` module similar to the one here: https://github.com/mrquincle/polychronization/blob/master/cmake/

Comment: Please, share your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @Gluttton: Added in the edit

Comment: 1. use `make VERBOSE=1` to recognise what exactly parameter passed to compiler and linker. 2. If `libplplotcxxd.so` passed to linker try realize is it contain function `c_plinit` for this purpose use command: `nm -D -C -g <pat to lib>/libplplotcxxd.so | grep c_plinit`.

Comment: And one more... Try using `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main ${PLplot_LIBRARY})` or `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main ${PLplot_cxx_LIBRARY})` instead of: `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main ${PLplot_LIBRARIES})`

Comment: Next: you don't need to do it: `SET(PLplot_LIBRARIES ${PLplot_LIBRARIES} ${PLplot_cxx_LIBRARY})` it's already done in the `FindPlplot.cmake`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your 2nd suggestion solved my problem :) `${PLplot_LIBRARY}` (which is `/usr/local/lib/libplplotd.so`) should be used instead of `${PLplot_cxx_LIBRARY}` (which is `/usr/local/lib/libplplotcxxd.so`)... I guess because my code is in C rather than Cpp. Post it as an answer if you want for me to accept it.